# Typescript angular and yeoman

Tags: angularjs, typescript, yo

What is a best way to kik start a project of angular and Typescript ?
Should I us the official yo angular and add on it 
or is it a good stable generator that will help me with the inertial kikstart

Answer (score 1):

We are currently developing with a friend a Typescript + Angular + Express generator for Yeoman :

https://github.com/NovaeWorkshop/nova

It is still under heavy development but already works and we use it to develop a real production website for a client.

It is a port from a previous great Yeoman generator [Bangular](https://github.com/42Zavattas/generator-bangular) where we added Typescript, UI Router and Desktop builds with Electron (Atom shell).

At the moment tests are broken and documentation is not up to date, but it's gonna come back real soon, and we would be happy to have your feedback on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure yo is a great tool for scaffolding angular. It wants to put controllers in a controller directory and services in a service directory.

This structure is fine, but there are other structures that may serve you better. There are feature and component structures that group related controllers and services together.

You are going to want to define your services and controllers as classes with Typescript. It is always the best to register your controller with Angular is PascalCase because a unique class instance is returned. Services should be registered as camelCase as only a singleton instance Is returned.

I would recommend looking up Basarat's Angular with Typescript examples and John Papa Angular style guide.

Comment: I am fine with the current yo angularjs folder structure I know that could be better different one but I still looking for some simple kik start

Comment: That is purely dependent on which generator you use. generator-angular might, but something like generator-ngbp uses a modular approach as opposed to the "sock drawer" approach you describe.